# The deployment identity does not match the subscription

Tags: clickonce

I have a WPF application deployed using ClickOnce.
I'm about to buy a certificate to sign it.
I know I will have to reinstall the application on clients after I sign it with my certificate.
My question is, once my certificate expires and I'll have to renew it, I'll get the error "The deployment identity does not match the subscription" again?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a similar problem here where I get the same error: "The deployment identity does not match the subscription." In my case, my hard-drive broke and I lost the original certificate, so I requested a new one.

Unfortunately, using a new certificate (doesn't matter if the subscriber is you again) will trigger the error. The old certificate MUST be renewed instead. Which makes me think that without a doubt your certificate was re-issued instead of renewed. Double-check to make sure this wasn't the case.